# Http links on Flutter not working on Android devices

Tags: android, flutter

With the help of [uni_links](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links) library, I am connecting the payment screen in the browser with the app, to link back to the app once payment is successful. It all works as expected on iOS, and app is opened with return url. But on Android callback is not even called, that notifies me about the return url, even though the app is opened, meaning http linking part works.

This is what I've added in Android Manifest file:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data
        android:scheme="https"
        android:host="www.redirect.mydomain.eu"
        android:pathPrefix="/return_url"/>
</intent-filter>
```

And this is the callback from uni_links that I am listening to in order for it to trigger with the return url string, but it doesn't trigger on Android at all:

```
_subscription = getLinksStream().listen((String link) {
  // Handle success case
}, onError: (err) {
  // Handle exception by warning the user their action did not succeed
});
```

Any idea why this is not working on Android at all?

Comment: you need to have internet permission in the AndroidManifest for your app to access internet

Comment: internet permission android - 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: That one is covered, I do have internet permission written at the top of the manifest file, outside of intent-filter section.

Comment: You talk about http but have specified https in the manifest.

Comment: May be the problem is that you didn't create "assetlink.json"-file or haven't made it available on your server?

Comment: I do have this json file on the server, and redirect back to the app works fully. It's just that I don't get this callback triggered after app is opened.

Comment: @Henry App Links only work with https scheme and require a specified host, plus a hosted file - assetlinks.json. With http I wanted to clarify that it's about App Links on Android, and not Deep Links and custom schemes.

Comment: Hi Aleksandar! I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?